# Adjusting the view after the appearance of the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

I am having an issue when I try to adjust the position of a textView and of a button when the keyboard appears.

I tried this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...Code here .. //
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidHide:", name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

}
func keyboardDidShow(notification :NSNotification){
    //println("A aparut")
    print("\(self.messageText.frame.origin)")
    var c = notification.userInfo
    var keyboardInfo = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary
    var keyboardFrameBegin = keyboardInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).size as CGSize

    // UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)

    //UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.25);
    //print(" is the height \(self.messageText.frame.height)")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0 , animations: {
        self.ChatView.frame = CGRectMake(self.ChatView.frame.origin.x, self.ChatView.frame.origin.y , self.ChatView.frame.width, 150 )
        self.sendButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.sendButton.frame.origin.x, self.sendButton.frame.origin.y + keyboardFrameBegin.height, self.sendButton.frame.width , self.sendButton.frame.height)
        self.messageText.frame = CGRectMake(self.messageText.frame.origin.x,self.messageText.frame.origin.y +  keyboardFrameBegin.height ,self.messageText.frame.width,self.messageText.frame.height);
    })

    //UIView.commitAnimations()        
}
```

and I get a nil error when I try to get the value for the key.

What should I replace the line with?

One more thing that I noticed when I tried to hardcode this issue [ added 200 to y for each element when it appears and substracting 200 when it dissapears] is that the methods are called more than once.

What I mean by this is that the frame is going further and further up until it reaches the moon.

Is it the simulator or what?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @frank21 I kind of did.The issue was kind of weird.what I did was rather basic,I hardcoded the coordinates depending on the device.There are no problems when I just move the frame to some coordinates and I don't know if it's the simulator or not to be blamed

Comment: Would you mind writing down the heights you used for the different keyboards? I've been trying to find them but just can't seem to get it right

Comment: @frank21 I did something better.I checked my whole project and I pasted the whole event when the keyboard appeared. Here is the link http://swiftstub.com/911055864/